# is RGB to CMYK conversion 1:1?

Tags: colors, rgb, cmyk

*If I do not filter through an ICC profile*, is CMYK to RGB conversion 1:1?
Looks like it when using [color pickers like this one](http://www.dematte.at/colorPicker/#top).

Comment: The question [Are RGB numeric values equal to CMYK percentages?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/5022) might also be interesting.

Comment: That color picker produces different results from Photoshop color picker. Photoshop color picker returns same CMYK for certain RGB combinations (e.g. colors near bright red edge).

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not. CMYK and RGB have a lot of colors in common, but not all. Both contain colors the other does not.

Illustrative chart:
http://static.photo.net/attachments/bboard/00Q/00QOnx-61877884.jpg

Comment: Very helpful chart, thx.  However is it not true that you can map the values from one space to the other (using a naive algorithm like the one in the link above)... they are just out of cmyk bounds sometimes/oftentimes.

Comment: Sure there are conversion algorithms that would find a closest match. If you're wondering if there's a matching pair of algorithms that allows one to convert back and forth between RGB and CMYK without losing data... I'd guess no but I'm not sure about that at all.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify (for myself) that implementations like this one: http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-color-conversion.html  can, while making very little sense, produce 1:1 mappings.  E.g. ColorConverter.toRGB( ColorConverter.toCMYK( new RGB(0,255,255) ) ); returns the selfsame values as the RGB param.

Comment: This chart is now a dead link.

Answer (score 0):

I found [the theoretical answer here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/11049/13984) helpful:

> From a theoretical viewpoint, there's no question that conversion from
>   RGB to CMYK can be completely lossless, so (for example) you can do a
>   round-trip conversion (RGB to CMYk, then back to RGB) and guarantee
>   that the result is identical to the original input.